# How to transform this dataset to the following dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

Input

```
+------+------+------+------+
|emp_name|emp_area| dept|zip| 
+------+------+------+------+
|ram|USA|"Sales"|805912|     
|sham|USA|"Sales"|805912|   
|ram|Canada|"Marketing"|805912|   
|ram|USA|"Sales"|805912|
|sham|USA|"Marketing"|805912|      
+------+------+------+------
```

Desired output

```
feature   |Top1 name |Top 1 value1|Top2 name|top 2 value|

emp_name    ram |3|sham |2
emp_area    Usa |4|canada |1    
dept       sales|3|Marketing|3
zip         805912|5|NA|NA
```

I started with dynamically generating the count for each one of them but unable to store them in a dataset

```
val features=ds.columns.toList
for (e <- features) {
  val ds1=ds.groupBy(e).count().sort(desc("count")).limit(5).withColumnRenamed("count", e+"_count")
}
```

Now how to collect all the values into one dataframe and transform to the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly verbose approach. You can `map` each column to a dataframe with one row, which corresponds to the row in the desired output. Add NA columns if necessary. Convert the column names to the desired ones, and finally do a `unionAll` to combine the dataframes (one row each).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val top = 2

val result = ds.columns.map(
    c => ds.groupBy(c).count()
           .withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.orderBy(desc("count"))))
           .filter(s"rn <= $top")
           .groupBy().pivot("rn")
           .agg(first(col(c)), first(col("count")))
           .select(lit(c), col("*"))
).map(df => 
    if (df.columns.size != 1 + top*2)
        df.select(List(col("*")) ::: (1 to (top*2+1 - df.columns.size)).toList.map(x => lit("NA")): _*)
    else df
).map(df =>
    df.toDF(List("feature") ::: (1 to top).toList.flatMap(x => Seq(s"top$x name", s"top$x value")): _*)
).reduce(_ unionAll _)

result.show
+--------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| feature|top1 name|top1 value|top2 name|top2 value|
+--------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
|emp_name|      ram|         3|     sham|         2|
|emp_area|      USA|         4|   Canada|         1|
|    dept|    Sales|         3|Marketing|         2|
|     zip|   805912|         5|       NA|        NA|
+--------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: first we are looping each of the columns and applying the pivot and group by and selecting the columns can you explain the code from the map after this ?

Comment: The second map adds NA columns to ensure that all the dataframes have the same number of columns. The third map changes the column names of the dataframes to match your desired output.